# Callback set in the state variable of Context Provider will be undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have referred other questions asked here by OPs but none seems to work for me. I have one layout and in that layout there is one toolbar which I am using to submit forms. Now to make that happen I using one `FormProvider` which is a `Context.Provider` (wraps layout component) with a state variable which stores function callback to submit a form. Now in the form component (which is loaded conditionally) I am using this setState func from context to assign form submit callback and in the toolbar using state variable from context to call that as a function. The problem I am facing is I always get state variable from context `undefined`. These are the snippets from my code.

**FormProvider**

```
type FormContextProps = {
    setOnSubmit: (callable: Function | undefined) => void
    assignOnSubmit: Dispatch<any>
    setOnCancel: (callable: Function | undefined) => void
    submit: (e: any) => void
    cancel: () => void
}

const initAuthContextPropsState = {
    setOnSubmit: () => { },
    assignOnSubmit: () => { },
    setOnCancel: () => { },
    submit: (e: any) => { },
    cancel: () => { },
}

const FormContext = createContext<FormContextProps>(initAuthContextPropsState)

const useTForm = () => {
    return useContext(FormContext)
}

const FormProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
    const [onSubmit, assignOnSubmit] = useState<Function | undefined>()
    const [onCancel, assignOnCancel] = useState<Function | undefined>()

    const setOnSubmit = (callable: Function | undefined) => {
        console.log('setOnSubmit', callable)
        assignOnSubmit(callable)
        console.log('setOnSubmit after', onSubmit)
    }

    const setOnCancel = (callable: Function | undefined) => {
        assignOnCancel(callable)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("changed onSubmit"); // this hook is called only on first render
    }, [onSubmit])

    const submit = (e: any) => {
        console.log('form submited', onSubmit) // this is always undefined when I click on save button on toolbar
        if (onSubmit) onSubmit(e)
    }

    const cancel = () => {
        if (onCancel) onCancel()
    }

    return (
        <FormContext.Provider value={{ setOnSubmit, assignOnSubmit, setOnCancel, submit, cancel }}>
            {children}
        </FormContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

**Toolbar**

```
const FormToolbar: FC = () => {
  const {classes} = useLayout()

  const {submit, cancel} = useTForm()

  const submitForm = (e: any) => submit(e)

  return (
    <div className='toolbar' id='kt_toolbar'>
      {/* begin::Container */}
      <div
        id='kt_toolbar_container'
        className={clsx(classes.toolbarContainer.join(' '), 'd-flex flex-stack')}
      >
        <DefaultTitle />

        {/* begin::Actions */}
        <div className='py-1 d-flex align-items-center'>
          
          {/* begin::Button */}

          <button
            className='btn btn-sm btn-primary me-4'
            onClick={submitForm}
          >
            Save
          </button>

          <button
            className='btn btn-sm btn-primary'
            onClick={cancel}
          >
            Cancel
          </button>
          {/* end::Button */}
        </div>
        {/* end::Actions */}
      </div>
      {/* end::Container */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**EditForm.tsx**

```
const EditForm: React.FC<Props> = () = {
    const form = useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLFormElement>
    const { setOnSubmit, assignOnSubmit } = useTForm()

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        setOnSubmit(() => { form?.current.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit')) });
        console.log('Form changed', form)
    }, [form])

    return (
        <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit} ref={form}>
            // ...
        </form>
    );
    
}
```

**Main Component**

```
function StaffManagement({ user, selectedLanguageId, idMenu }: Props) {

  const [editing, setEditing]: [any, Function] = useState(null)

  return (
    <div className='row'>
      <div className="col-lg-4">
        <ModuleItemList
          className='card-xxl-stretch mb-xl-3'
          edit={setEditing}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="col-lg-8">
        {editing && <EditForm
         userId={user.id}
         menuId={idMenu}
        />}
      </div>
    </div>
  )

}
```

Comment: where did you trigger `submit()` from `FormProvider`?

Comment: @IhsanFajarRamadhan sorry I forgot to add Toolbar where I actually call submit, I have updated my code to add toolbar code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using setState, we can do it in two ways,

1. `setState(newState); // directly pass the new state`
2. `setState((currentState) => newState); // return the new state from a callback fn`

That mean setState can accept a plain state value or a callback function which will return the new state that need to be set as the new state.

When you say,

```
  const setOnSubmit = (callable: Function | undefined) => {
      // callable => () => { form?.current.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit')) }
      assignOnSubmit(callable)
  }
```

Here React thinks you used the `setState`(assignOnSubmit) in the 2nd way I mentioned above, so react will call your callback and execute the `form?.current.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'))`. Since your `callable` function returns nothing, `undefined` will assigned to your `onSubmit` state.

So if you really need to store this function in a state, you have to do it as,

```
   const setOnSubmit = (callable: Function | undefined) => {
      assignOnSubmit(() => callable) // React will call the callback and return callable
  }
```

**Few Other Tips**

---

1. Also do not use `useLayoutEffect` for this task. You can use `useEffect` and imrpove the performance of your application.

---

2. memoize the provider data, otherwise you will trigger unwanted re renders.

```
  const data = useMemo(() => ({
    setOnSubmit, assignOnSubmit, setOnCancel, submit, cancel
  }), [submit, cancel, setOnCancel, assignOnSubmit, setOnSubmit])

  return (
      <FormContext.Provider value={data}>
          {children}
      </FormContext.Provider>
  )
```

---

3. State updates are asynchronous. So you can't expect to `console.log` log the latest state

```
  const setOnSubmit = (callable: Function | undefined) => {
      console.log('setOnSubmit', callable)
      assignOnSubmit(() => callable)
      console.log('setOnSubmit after', onSubmit) // this won't log the latest as assignOnSubmit is async
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Doing like this `assignOnSubmit(() => callable)` as you suggested solved the problem. But not sure why the `formik.handleSubmit` is not triggered. I verified form submission by adding `form.current.addEventListener('submit', () => console.log(''Form Submitted))`. Any ideas?

Comment: try, `setOnSubmit(() => { formik.submitForm() });` note: `const formik  = useFormik()`

Comment: thanks for your input, this solves all my problems...

Answer (score 0):

you need to make `<FormProvider` as a parent of your `Toolbar` and `EditForm` to make your context working properly. Based on your code I don't see where you put the `<FormProvider`, so I'm guessing that you need to put it on your `Main Component`

#### Main Component

```
function StaffManagement({ user, selectedLanguageId, idMenu }: Props) {

  const [editing, setEditing]: [any, Function] = useState(null)

  return (
   <FormProvider>
    <div className='row'>
      <div className="col-lg-4">
        <ModuleItemList
          className='card-xxl-stretch mb-xl-3'
          edit={setEditing}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="col-lg-8">
        {editing && <EditForm
         userId={user.id}
         menuId={idMenu}
        />}
      </div>
    </div>
   </FormProvider>
  )
```

Comment: I have updated the code the code add toolbar components code where I am actually calling submit function..

Comment: FormProvider is in the `App.tsx` so it is on the top of layout component. So both Toolbar and main component comes under FormProvider down somewhere in the tree. And Toolbar is not inside main component or EditForm component it is under layout component as it is common on every page.